# Add Service Reference and Add Web Reference?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, web-services, windows-phone-7

I am trying to add web reference to web service (http://jira.atlassian.com/rpc/soap/jirasoapservice-v2?wsdl), however 'Add Web Reference' is greyed out in my VS. So i added the web service link as Add Service Reference, VS recognized the web service but now i am having issue with displaying right classes. (Note: The 'Add Web Reference is greyed out for Windows Phone project but it is not greyed out for regular Console Application). When i add web service as web reference, i get access to `JiraSoapServiceService` class. so i can do something like this:

```
//jiraWS is name of web service
jiraWS.JiraSoapServiceService jira = new JiraSoapServiceService();
```

However when i add web service as service reference, i cannot get access to `JiraSoapServiceService` class and i need to have access to this class, in order to make call to web methods.

Does anyone know how i can fix this?

Comment: When you use Service Reference (WCF) a suffix "Client" is added to the class name. JiraSoapServiceServiceClient ?

Answer (score 41):

When you click on Add Service Reference click on Advanced - then at the bottom of the Popup is an option to add a Web Reference :)

Comment: as i said, it is greyed out. try creating a windows phone project and add web reference clicking on Advanced button.  http://img130.imageshack.us/img130/6305/problempx.jpg

Comment: I know this did not answer his question or provide him with a solution, but it helped me tremendously.  I could not figure out how to add a Web Reference to a Windows Service project but you guided me directly to it.  Thanks stack72!

Comment: Advanced option worked me. Thank you!

Comment: hmm, was greyed out in VS 2022 in context menu for an old project, but advanced options worked