# Add Service Reference in .NET Core in Visual Studio for Mac

Tags: asp.net-core, service-reference, visual-studio-mac

As far as I know, in Windows I was able to add a service reference in a .NET Core project in Visual Studio 2017 by installing the [Visual Studio WCF Connected Service](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=erikcai-MSFT.VisualStudioWCFConnectedService), but I wasn't able to find that same extension in Visual Studio for Mac.

Is there any other way of adding a service reference in Mac?

Comment: Currently VS for Mac does not support for creating WCF service references for .NET Core projects. Maybe the extension for VS on Windows provides a command line svcutil tool that could be used on the Mac? Otherwise can you just create it in VS 2017 on Windows.

Comment: @MattWard Are you aware if it at least support it for .NET standard projects, or none at all?

Comment: By .NET Core projects I meant all Sdk style projects so that includes .NET Standard projects. You an add a WCF reference to other projects, such as those that target .NET Framework.

Comment: The extension for VS on Windows provides a dotnet-svcutil application that you can run on the command line if you have .NET Core 1.0.5 runtime installed. You can download that on the Mac, rename it to .zip, then extract the contents.

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio for Mac "Community" 7.8.3 (build 2), right-click on the project name in the Solution Explorer. Then select Add -> Add Web Reference.

I had the choice between WFC and .NET 2.0 Web Services

I'm using .NET, so I can't verify WFC is functional, but it appears to be there

Comment: Just downloaded that build and the option doesn't appear for me. Do you have any other things installed?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6830706/add-service-reference-and-add-web-reference/6830762#6830762 When I changed my project from .NET Core to 4.5.1 framework I had to find the link in a different place. Hope this helps.